# Installing apps on external SD card on Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean

Tags: applications, external-sd, installation, 4.2-jelly-bean, insufficient-memory

I am using Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean on TI OMAP 5 platform. I want to install applications on an external SD card, but even if a lot of space is free (more than 25MB), I am getting an error "Insufficient storage".

1. Is it possible to install applications on an external SD card in Jelly Bean?
2. How can I move an application installed on internal memory to an external SD card?

Comment: Please check the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for details and first-aid.

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-install-apps-onto-your-SD-Card-No-Root/

Answer (score 0):

You can't install directly to the SD card. In many cases you can move much of the app and its data to the SD card, but the OS and the app have to support it. Even then, you need to install normally and then move it.

Comment: Not 100% correct. One can set the "install target" to "2" (sd-card), so apps supporting this will get installed there. Culprit is, though, that prior to installation the `.apk` must be downloaded. And this download goes to `/data/local`, which is on internal storage. Second culprit is the app in question must support to be installed on sdcard. See the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for details ;)

Comment: Thanks , but how will i move the applications from internal to external as their is no support of move to sdcard in settings app in jellybean

Answer (score -1):

You can't install an app to SD unless your phone has internal storage, but you can move the data of your desired app. For that, follow this: Open Settings > More > App manager > then open the apps you want to move to SD card, then select "Move to SD storage".